# Здравствуйте, подскажите как мне сделать так чтобы при наведение на блок-div он затемнялся и появлялась кнопка подробнее с ссылкой,в html, css

Tags: html, css

Нужно чтобы при наведении на блок-div он затемнялся и появлялась надпись подробнее с ссылкой на страницу где собственно всё будет описано. Только не через тег title это не то. Я знаю про псевдокласс hover и атрибут opacity. Но я не знаю как сделать эту кнопку подробнее?Поскажите плиз!

Comment: HTML<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Читы на CS_GO</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href = "CS_GO.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="menu">
<h1 class = "CS_GO">Читы на CS:GO</h1>
<ul class = "cheats">
<li id = "cheat_1">gh68h6hh65</li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: CSS   body
{
background-image : url(картинки/фон.jpg);
background-position : fixed;
background-size : 146.41%;
background-repeat : no-repeat;
}
.menu
{
 width : 63%;
 background : black;
 margin-left : 18.3%;
 margin-right : 18.3%;
 color : white;
 text-align : center;
 position : absolute;
 min-height : 130.21%;
}
.cheats
{
 list-style : none;
 text-align : left;
 margin-left : -4%;
 width : 99%;
}
#cheat_1
{
 border : 2px #FAFAD2 solid;
 padding : 1%;
 text-align : left;
}
.cheat img
{
 float:left;
 margin : 1%;
}
.CS_GO
{
 color : #FFFF00;
}

Comment: #cheat_1:hover
{
 opacity : 0.3;
}

Comment: ну это всё я только начинающий програмист и не до конца понимаю вссе тонкости

Comment: мне просто нужно чтобы был всплывающий текст с ссылкой

Answer (score 2):

...для дальнейших вопросах чтобы добавить пример кода
если захочешь добавить выполняемый код то второй с права от отметки
... [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

потом после добавление кода отмечаешь все начиная со второй строки и нажимаешь ctrl+k чтобы все выровнять...

вот решение

```css
.elem{
  transition: background-color 1s ease;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.elem a{
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.elem:hover{
  background-color: burlywood;
}

.elem:hover a{
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="elem">
    <a href="https://www.google.com">link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: @Sevastopol обычно минуса что то поменялось?))))))

Comment: СПС, а чтоделает background-color  в transition?

Comment: а понял это типо transition-property

Comment: @ДаниилДоронин да можно конечно указать all но так по эффективнее